# how to add class to ul element by using zend navigation?

Tags: php, zend-framework, class, zend-navigation

i've got a simple navigation menu like this:

```
$container = new Zend_Navigation();
$container->addPage(array(
    'label' => 'Page 1',
    'uri'   => 'page-1',
    'foo'   => 'bar',
    'pages' => array(
        array(
            'label' => 'Page 1.1',
            'uri'   => 'page-1.1',
            'foo'   => 'bar',
        ),
        array(
            'label' => 'Page 1.2',
            'uri'   => 'page-1.2',
            'class' => 'my-class',
        )
    ),
...
```

this will generate :

```
ul
  li
  li
```

how do i ass a class / id to the `ul` or to the `li` ?

any ideas?

thanks

edit: i found a different solution:

i use this function

```
public static function htmlify($container, $menu_name = null)
{
    $i = 0;
    $menu = '<ul class="'.$menu_name.'">';
    foreach($container as $page)
    {
        $menu .= '<li id="'.$page->htmlfyId.'"><a id="menu-'.$page->id.'" class="'.$page->class.'" href="'.$page->uri.'">'.$page->label.'</a>';
        $menu .= '<ul id="'.$page->htmlfyClass.'">';

        foreach($page as $pages)
        {
            $menu .= '<li id="li"><a class="'.$page->class.'" href="'.$pages->uri.'">'.$pages.'</a></li>';
        }
        $menu .= '</li>';
        $menu .= '</ul>';
    }
return $menu;
}
```

then in the method that holds the menu add:

```
    $view = Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->getView();

$menu = self::htmlify($container, 'navigation');

    $view->menu = $menu;
    return $menu;
```

my class has static methods and u have to `echo class::method` in the view, otherwise just use a regular `$this->menu` or whatever.

then u can use it like this:

```
$container = new Zend_Navigation();
$container->addPage(array(
    'label' => 'Page 1',
    'uri'   => 'page-1',
    'foo'   => 'bar',

    'htmlfyId' => 'testing',
    'htmlfyClass' => 'test',

    'pages' => array(
        array(
            'label' => 'Page 1.1',
            'uri'   => 'page-1.1',
            'foo'   => 'bar',
        ),
        array(
            'label' => 'Page 1.2',
            'uri'   => 'page-1.2',
            'class' => 'my-class',
        )
    ),
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a class on ul try this

```
$options['ulClass'] = 'foo';

<?php echo $this->menu($container)->renderMenu($container,$options); ?>
```

where $container is your Zend_Navigation object.